# Can WFI be replaced with WFE here

Tags: assembly, arm, linux-device-driver, arm64

We have  following snippet that is used to switch from AARCH32 to AARCH64 using RMR register.

http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/include/asm/arch-sunxi/boot0.h;hb=HEAD

```
/*
 * Configuration settings for the Allwinner A64 (sun50i) CPU
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0+
*/

#if defined(CONFIG_RESERVE_ALLWINNER_BOOT0_HEADER) && !defined(CONFIG_SPL_BUILD)
/* reserve space for BOOT0 header information */
     b  reset
    .space  1532
#elif defined(CONFIG_ARM_BOOT_HOOK_RMR)
/*
* Switch into AArch64 if needed.
* Refer to arch/arm/mach-sunxi/rmr_switch.S for the original source.
*/
  tst     x0, x0                  // this is "b #0x84" in ARM
  b       reset
. space  0x7c
.word   0xe59f1024  // ldr     r1, [pc, #36] ; 0x170000a0
.word   0xe59f0024  // ldr     r0, [pc, #36] ; CONFIG_*_TEXT_BASE
.word   0xe5810000  // str     r0, [r1]
.word   0xf57ff04f  // dsb     sy
.word   0xf57ff06f  // isb     sy
.word   0xee1c0f50  // mrc     15, 0, r0, cr12, cr0, {2} ; RMR
.word   0xe3800003  // orr     r0, r0, #3
.word   0xee0c0f50  // mcr     15, 0, r0, cr12, cr0, {2} ; RMR
.word   0xf57ff06f  // isb     sy
.word   0xe320f003  // wfi
.word   0xeafffffd  // b       @wfi
.word   0x017000a0  // writeable RVBAR mapping address
 #ifdef CONFIG_SPL_BUILD
.word   CONFIG_SPL_TEXT_BASE
 #else
.word   CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE
 #endif
 #else
/* normal execution */
 b  reset
 #endif
```

At line 27 and 28 wfi is used to put core into low power state and core would be waken up when some interrupts happen.

I have few queries:

1. Can instructions after `wfi` and `b .` , would executes as it is ?
2. Can WFE be used in place of `wfi` to similar job and waken up by SEVL just after B. ?

Comment: Generally, SO folks will never respond to linked code. If you want help with code, post the minimal, verifiable, code snippet inline.

Comment: The code is strange as it is mixed AARCH32 and AARCH64.  The 'assembler' is AARACH64, but it can be executed in AARCH32 mode.  If so, the code is trying to transition to AARCH64 mode.  The 'RMR' is written with TEXT_BASE, so it is assumed that 'wfi\n b .' will terminate when the AARCH64 transition takes place.  The `wfi` is AARCH32 and I believe that `wfe` is the same thing.  This just says to take exceptions/interrupts while the RMR transition to AARCH64 is in progress.  You should ask on u-boot mailing lists.  I guess it is easier to post to SO.

Comment: Thanks @artlessnoise, My questions are bit generic. Once wfi gets executed it puts the core into low power state, does it mean core won't execute any further instruction  till core is interrupted and get out of standby mode ?

Comment: Yes.  Here is [what is the purpose of WFI and WFE](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka15473.html).  The WFE is different in multi-core situations.  But with the `b .-4` following it just re-executes in any wake-up case.  I don't see how `WFE` would be more useful?  The specific 'power-down' of WFI/WFE is dictated by some SOC registers.  Typically you can pick the power-down states; but the deeper the sleep, the more setup/restore you must do.  For instance if you execute from DDR, you can not power it off.

Comment: ok, but b .(branch to itself) gets executed which is after WFI ? You mean it would execute only in case of wake up from WFI ?

Comment: It is not `b .`, it is `b @wfi`, it branches back an instruction.  0xfffd is '-3' and the PC is two ahead; all instruction are 4 bytes so it is `b .-4` or preceding instruction.  Does it make sense when you believe that?  0xfffe is a `b .`  offset.

Comment: ok, Thanks, if you don't mind my follow-up stupid query is , is there any way to really tell that wfi has run effectively  and core is put to low power state? I believe untill wfi has run well , switch to aarch64 will not take place. I mean do we need to program specific SOC registers for WFI to work ?